# Android Automotive CarSensorManager for SRS sensors

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-auto, android-automotive

Does in Android Automotive exists a way to read sensors from OBD2 or SRS. Or in any other android OS for cars.
I have searched in CarSensorManager but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Currently not from AOSP implementation.
To read a sensor data usually you need to access/read data from vehicle network (CAN bus) that mean you need someone to transfer that data to Android Stack first and make it visible in Android IVI domain. 
Normarly Vehicle HAL suppose to be doing it... but it highly depend on OEM if they offer that signal or not.